# Envoy Proxy on Kubernetes gives 503

Tags: kubernetes, envoyproxy

I am kubernetizing (if I can use that term), [this](https://github.com/yokawasa/envoy-proxy-demos/tree/master/fault-injection) demo, and I am getting 503 from the front service.

So, what I have done is to create three services; green, blue and red, and all they work fine. If I hit them directly, I get 200, but when I do it through the front service, I get 503.

The idea of the demo is to hit a front service, and this one proxies the request, depending on the path, to one of the services behind (green, blue or red). This is the front service envoy yaml file:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/service/blue"
                route:
                  cluster: service_blue
              - match:
                  prefix: "/service/green"
                route:
                  cluster: service_green
              - match:
                  prefix: "/service/red"
                route:
                  cluster: service_red
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
            config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: service_blue
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: blue
        port_value: 80
  - name: service_green
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: green
        port_value: 80
  - name: service_red
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: red
        port_value: 80
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8001
```

These are my services in the cluster:

```
# kubectl get svc -n envoy-demo
NAME    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
blue    ClusterIP   10.98.101.176    <none>        80/TCP    5h31m
front   ClusterIP   10.98.119.222    <none>        80/TCP    73m
green   ClusterIP   10.107.136.62    <none>        80/TCP    54m
red     ClusterIP   10.101.240.162   <none>        80/TCP    160m
```

If I access `front` pod and I curl any of the services, I get 200:

```
root@envoy-front-54856466dc-59jdw:/# curl blue/service/blue -I
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 166
Server: Werkzeug/0.16.0 Python/3.7.4
Date: Mon, 14 Oct 2019 15:53:14 GMT

root@envoy-front-54856466dc-59jdw:/# curl green/service/green -I
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 170
Server: Werkzeug/0.16.0 Python/3.7.4
Date: Mon, 14 Oct 2019 15:53:31 GMT

root@envoy-front-54856466dc-59jdw:/# curl red/service/red -I
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 163
Server: Werkzeug/0.16.0 Python/3.7.4
Date: Mon, 14 Oct 2019 15:53:38 GMT
```

These services return 200 on `/service/whatever` actually.

If I curl to the localhost or from outside the pod to the `front` service, I get 503:

```
# curl localhost/service/red
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination
```

Same, if I curl the IP of `front` service and and the service name, from outside the `front` pod.

The service ideally is running:

```
# netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6/envoy         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6/envoy
```

In case, it is relevant, this is the service envoy yaml file:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: service
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/service"
                route:
                  cluster: local_service
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
            config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: local_service
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8080
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8081
```

All the services are very similar; one of them is a normal service, the other one adds a delay, and the other one aborts 50% of the requests.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I have understood correctly you are trying to reach from localhost services inside your kubernetes cluster. So from kubernetes cluster point of view how did you deploy envoy?

Comment: Im doing it in my docker image. A load the config files with `envoy -c file.yaml`. Note that Im not only trying to reach these services from the localhost. I also curl `front` pod from outside, with `curl front/service/red` with same result.

Comment: Please follow this [tutorial](https://blog.markvincze.com/how-to-use-envoy-as-a-load-balancer-in-kubernetes/) it looks like you should expose your internal resources to the outside of the cluster using envoy or other controller like [nginx](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/)